# I want to return the title to each array instead of a set number. JSON Decoding Swift

Tags: arrays, json, swift, xcode, decoding

While decoding a JSON, I am wanting to return the title for each object in the array. Right now I have a 0 in the array. When I print, all I get is the first title. How can I fix my code.
This is what I have

```
let decodedData = try decoder.decode(ProductResponse.self, from: productTitle)
            print(decodedData.results[0].title)
```

This is my model for the JSON

```
struct ProductResponse: Decodable {
    let results: [SearchResults]
}

struct SearchResults: Decodable {
    let title: String
    let id:Int
}
```

[JSON I am decoding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVAeN.png)

Comment: Learn how to do a "for loop". That's maybe the key words you were missing. It's basic in coding.

Comment: [for loop in swift](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ControlFlow.html#ID121) but I recommend reading much more of that book if you are a beginner (and actually want to learn the language)

Answer (score 0):

You have to loop over the `results`.

```
let decodedData = try decoder.decode(ProductResponse.self, from: productTitle)
for result in decodedData.results {
    print(result.title)
}
```